# Airflow: Rerunning DAG can't load XCOMs from previous run

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to persist an XCOM value during re-runs of a DAG step (after clearing the status)?

Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish, namely when a DAG step status is cleared and the step re-run, I would like to be able to load the XCOM value pushed on the previous run. However, even though I can see the value in the XCOM interface, the value does not get pulled. I've looked through the source code for the `pull_xcom()` method but can't figure out where it is being filtered out.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is to maintain some amount of state between failed runs of a DAG. In the example, this would mean that 1 is added to the stored value every time the DAG step is cleared and rerun.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def test_step(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs.get('task_instance')
    value = ti.xcom_pull(key='key', include_prior_dates=True)

    if value is None:
        value = 0
    print(f'BEFORE VALUE: {value}')
    value += 1
    print(f'AFTER VALUE: {value}')

    ti.xcom_push(key='key', value=value)

    # Simulating a failure
    raise Exception


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Testing',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['test@test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    'test_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2020, 4, 9),
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_step',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=test_step,
    dag=dag,
)

t1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime a task is about to run, its XCom is cleared for the current execution date (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L960). This is why you won't ever pull values from previous task tries. Use of `include_prior_dates=True` only pulls from previous execution dates, but not previous runs of the same execution date.

One possible solution is to put a `DummyOperator` task upstream of your `test_step` task, called say `xcom_store.test_step`. Then use [airflow.models.XCom.set()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/xcom.py#L86-L122) directly in `test_step` to your XCom values into the `xcom_store.test_step` task (reference [xcom_push()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1510-L1515) as an example). When you need to pull, just pull as you usually would with but from the dummy task instead, i.e. `ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='xcom_store.test_step', key='key')`. Definitely not ideal and could lead to some confusion, but if you standardize it and build some helpers around it, it could be alright?

Comment: Hi @danielHuang So is the “primary key” (aka unique identifier) for the xcom pushed value is `dag_id,task_id, execution date combined `? I am curious about this, as I  want to know the re-runability of the task which relies on the pulled value to be stable, when the task is re-run.

Answer (score 0):

To add on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61580768/21925935), you don't need to actually have the `dummy` task existing in your DAG.

You can push Xcom to an non-existing task_id, as part of your dag.

E.g. in `PythonOperator` `python_callable` do:

```
XCom.set(key="your_key",
         value=value,
         execution_date=execution_date,
         task_id=task.task_id + "_some_suffix",
         dag_id=dag.dag_id
         )
```

and later retrieve it using:
`task_id="previous_task_id" + "_some_suffix"`, e.g. like so:

```
task_instance.xcom_pull(
        task_ids=task_instance.task_id + "_some_suffix",
        key="your_key",
        include_prior_dates=False)
```

Be careful, since this XCom will not get deleted on [reruns](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html).
It can be however overriden.

Comment: There is a foreign key relationship maintained between tables 'xcom' & 'task_instance'  with keys (dag_id, task_id, run_id, map_index). So, if you try to push to a non-existing task_id, Airflow will throw an exception. [version I tested, 2.4.3]